# Generate random dutch IBAN numbers

Tags: jmeter, iban

I have a Jmeter test plan where I want my HttpSampler to send a post request.

The body of the request should contain Json as follows:

```
{
  "iban": "${iban}",
  "name": "${name}",
  "phoneNumber": "0646875588",
  "termsAccepted": "true"
}
```

the IBAN is generated from a CSV file, but this is not what i want.

can I generate the IBAN with some code or something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [JSR223 sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) which supports python, beanshell and other languages. But it's a [bad practice](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean), it may be better to use pre-generated CSV instead:

> If your test needs large amounts of data - particularly if it needs to be randomised - create the test data in a file that can be read with CSV Dataset. This avoids wasting resources at run-time.